# Android sqlite - updating object deletes it

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having a problem with my update function and I tried several ways but it didn't work. I am trying to update an object that was changed before being sent to the function, and I want to use its id to update its fields:

```
public void update(T object) {
    if (object != null) {
        long id = object.getId();
        ContentValues cv = getContentValues(object);
        database.update(tableName, cv, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { id + "" });
    }
}
```

The function getContentValues(T) gets a ContentValue object filled with all the values of the columns of the object, except for the id. I tried adding the id too, but it didn't work.

Does anyone know why this function deletes my object instead of updating it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer doesn't have anything to do with the shown code, but with my getContentValues(T) function, where I put an object instead of his id in the concerned field.

Now I know it deletes the object instead of canceling the update!